# How do I check on what sequence I'm in ?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm playing assassin's creed III for quite some time now and I just(a few minutes ago)checked on how many homestead missions there are,and in most of the sites that I checked there would be,on the bottom : sequences.

So I searched but I couldn't find out what sequence I'm on now. So please help me.

Comment: This question is confusing. Your current memory sequence should be in the pause menu in the log. As it will show all memories up to your current one with the amount of completion.

Answer (score 3):

Assassin's Creed 3 does not display the current sequence in an obvious fassion. The easiest way to find out which sequence you are on is to go to the DNA progress tracker. There the sequences played previously have at least some sort of sync; this is not true for the current one. So the first mission not to have any sync at all is your current sequence.

Of course, you could also use third party sources. As much as I personally despise a lot of stuff that IGN does, their wiki sites provide excellent information. So you can always check the current sequence (according to your known storyline / current objectives) there.

http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-3

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what sequence you on, just pause your game and stay on the resume button, and above the box it'll say Sequence 01, 02, 03, 04, Ect. Hope that helped you